# Evaluate $\int_Y R \ dS.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> The spherical surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ has a charge with the density
>
> $$\rho(x,y,z)=\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2} \quad C/m^2.$$
>
> Determine the total charge of the sphere.

So I have two different parametrizations that I've attempted and my answer is very close to the correct one, which is $2\pi R^3$. Can someone check my two approaches to see where I make the mistakes?

---

### Method 1

The surface can be parametrized by

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    x & = & R\sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi} \\
    y & = & R\sin{\theta\sin{\varphi}} \\
    z & = & R\cos{\theta}
  \end{array}
\right. \implies D:\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
     0\leq \theta \leq \pi\\
     0\leq \varphi \leq 2\pi \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

A positionvector is $\vec{r}(\theta,\varphi)=R(\sin{\theta}\cos{\varphi},\sin{\theta\sin{\varphi}},\cos{\theta})$, thus the magnitude of the normalvector is

$$dS=||\vec{n}||d\theta d\varphi=||\vec{r}'_\theta\times\vec{r}'_\varphi||d\theta d\varphi=R^2\sin{\theta} \ d\theta d\varphi.$$

Putting things together I get

$$I=\iint_Y\rho \ dS=\iint_DR^2\sin{\theta}\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2} \ d\theta  d\varphi = \\ = \iint_DR^3\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta} \ d\theta d\varphi = 2\pi R^3\int_0^\pi \cos{\theta}\sin{\theta} \ d\theta d\varphi = 0.$$

However, if the upper bound for $\theta$ is $\pi/2$, the answer becomes correct. But I believe my bounds are correct since that is standard for spherical coordinates. What is wrong?

### Method 2

Just leaving the variables as they are I get the position vector expressed only in the variables $x$ and $y$ by

$$\vec{r}(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}),$$

so a the magnitude of the normalvector is

$$dS=||\vec{n}||dxdy=||\vec{r}'_x\times\vec{r}'_y||dx dy=\frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}} \ dxdy$$

and I get that

$$I=\iint_Y \rho \ dS=\iint_D R r \ drd\theta =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^RRr \ drd\theta=\pi R^3,$$

which is half of the correct answer.

Comment: With the bounds $0\le \theta \le \pi$ and $0\le \psi \le 2\pi$, the correct parametrization of the $R$-sphere in spherical coordinates is $x = R \cos(\theta)$, $y = R \sin(\theta) \cos(\psi)$, and $z = R\sin(\theta) \sin(\psi)$.

Comment: Why? I don't understand, what I've done is simply a standard parametrization. Identically as in my book.

Comment: Think about it geometrically: we slice the sphere into circles parallel to the $yz$-plane, which are parametrized by the angle $\theta$; then each of these circles has points parametrized by the angle $\psi$. Also, after substituting everything into the integral, we must evaluate $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} R^3 \sin(\theta) |\sin(\theta)| |\sin(\psi)| \, d\theta, d\psi$$ which does indeed come out to $2\pi R^3$. (It is the absolute value signs that make this integral nonzero)

Comment: Wow, this post really messed up my entire life. I don't doubt your mathematical skills, but seriosuly take a look at this site: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system Scroll down to Coordinate system conversions and you will see the exact same parametrization I've done. The azimuthal angle $\vartphi$ is measured from positive z axis to negative, hence it's between $0$ and $\pi$.

Comment: Ah, I see. It doesn't really make a difference; in your parametrization you're measuring from the positive z axis to negative, and in mine I was measuring from the positive x axis to negative. But it looks like yours is indeed the standard.

Comment: Yeah, I had the feeling that you just rotated the axis or something. But thanks for your input. The problem was that I forgot the absolute value around my cosine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method 2, setting $z=\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$ only gives you the upper hemisphere.  When you add in the integral over the lower hemisphere with $z=-\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$, you'll double the answer to get your missing factor of $2$.

In method 1 you again have an issue with the signs of square roots: $\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}$ is $R|\cos\theta|$, not $R\cos\theta$.  Correcting this, you get the right answer.  (Note that contrary to what you said, integrating from $0$ to $\pi/2$ does not give the right answer: it is still off by a factor of $2$, though it gives you the same answer as you got in method 2.)

Comment: Ofcourse, I totally forgot the lower half! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint....Your density function is actually $|z|$ or $|R\cos\theta|$

Comment: Sorry, It does not click. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Parseval Your density function (in spherical coordinates) is positive on $\;\left[0,\,\frac\pi2\right]\;$ , yet negative on the other half, so when you have $\;\sqrt{R^2\cos^2\theta}\;$, you **must** split the integration interval for $\;\theta\;$ in two...

Comment: So in your first method replace $\int_0^{\pi}...d\theta$ with $2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}...d\theta$